# Creating a multi-leveled dictionary from different dict and key/value sets - python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, networkx

**Context:** I generated a `networkx` graph with different transports stop stations. The only attributes each stop stations has is their `id`, `name`, `lon` and `lat` positions.

I want to add other attributes to each points, these attributes are found in 3 csv files that I opened as `dicts`: (I simplified them quite a lot for easier reading):

```py
stops_csv = DictReader(open(STOPS_FILE,'r'))
Dict2 = dict()
for stop in stops_csv:
    Dict2[stop['stop_id']] = stop


Dict2:   ### Dict gotten from the nx graph.
{'stop1': OrderedDict([('stop_id', 'stop1'),
              ('stop_name', 'name1'),
              ('lat', 'lat1'),
              ('lon', 'lon1')]),
 'stop2': OrderedDict([('stop_id', 'stop2'),
              ('stop_name', 'name2'),
              ('lat', 'lat2'),
              ('lon', 'lon2')]), ...}

Dict1:   ### Dict that links Dict2 and Dict3.
{'stop1': OrderedDict([('trip_id', 'trip1'),
              ('t1', '01:43:00'),
              ('t2', '01:43:00')]),
 'stop2': OrderedDict([('trip_id', 'trip2'),
              ('t1', '18:14:00'),
              ('t2', '18:14:00')]), ...}

Dict3:   ### Dict containing trip_id and route_id.
{'trip1': OrderedDict([('route_id', 'route1'),
              ('trip_id', 'trip1'),
              ('direction_id', '0')]),
 'trip2': OrderedDict([('route_id', 'route2'),
              ('trip_id', 'trip2'),
              ('direction_id', '0')]), ...}
```

I would like to link `Dict1`, `Dict2` and `Dict3` in one single multi-leveled `dict` that I plan to use in a `nx.set_node_attributes()` afterward.

For each stop_id of `Dict2`, I would like to add every `trip_id` corresponding that are in `Dict3`. And then, for each `trip_id` previously added, I would like to add every `route_id` corresponding that also are in `Dict3`.

**My issues are the followings:**

- I can't seem to accumulate values that have the same key instead of replacing them. 
  I tried what was proposed [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246687/how-to-add-to-python-dictionary-without-replacing) post but couldn't seem to make it work. So I tried another approach and bellow is what I did so far. Basically, for each `stop_id` there is one or more `trip_id` corresponding, however, I only get the very last `trip_id` value.

```py
test_dict = dict()

for s in Dict2: # 's' stands for stop.
    test_dict['{}'.format(s)] = {}
    for t in Dict3: # 't' stands for trip.
        test_dict['{}'.format(s)]['trip_id'] = t
print(test_dict)

>>> {'stop1': {'trip_id': 'tripn'},  #'tripn' corresponds to the last trip_id value.
 'stop2': {'trip_id': 'tripn'},
 'stop3': {'trip_id': 'tripn'},
 'stop4': {'trip_id': 'tripn'},
 'stop5': {'trip_id': 'tripn'}, ...}
```

- Also, one of the biggest issue I have is `route_id` not being a key but a value of `Dict3` and I have no idea how I am supposed to go about that. So any indications would be greatly appreciated here...

---

The outcome should look like this:

```py
{stop1
     trip1
          route1
     trip2
          route1

stop2
     trip3
          route1
     trip4
          route1
     trip5
          route2
...}
```

I know it doesn't seem logical to have `trip_id` before `route_id` but I won't work with it as much as `trip_id` so this outcome should make my future work easier in theory.

I have looked at many posts about creating nested dictionaries with python and especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth) that goes into multi-level dict but I still couldn't find a solution to my problem, so here I am.

I could always open the 3 `csv` as `dataframes`, `merge` them and then make the desired `dict` out of them but I don't know how to go about that either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to merge *all* information from the dictionaries, or just the stop-trip-route names like you specified. For the latter, here is some simple code that creates a dictionary with

```
  stop
    trip
      route
```

structure:

```
# initialise new dictionary
new_dict = {}

for stop in Dict2.keys():

    # access the "connection dict" and get the trip_id
    trip_ids = Dict1.get(stop).get('trip_id')

    # initialise trip dict
    trip_dict = {}

    # if there is only one trip_id, create a list with a single entry
    if not isinstance(trip_ids, list):
        trip_ids = [trip_ids]

    for trip_id in trip_ids:

        # using trip id, get route info:
        route_id = Dict3.get(trip_id).get('route_id')

        # combine information
        trip_dict[trip_id] = route_id

    new_dict[stop] = trip_dict
```

if a given `stop_id` has more than one `trip_id`, the new_dict will look like this:

```
new_dict = {
       'stop_01': {
            'trip1': 'route1',
            'trip2': 'route2' 
                  }
            }
```

you can verify this by accessing the keys:

```
new_dict['stop_01'].keys()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ideally I would like to merge all informations but I'll start with the stop-trip-route combo and work from here. What you posted gives me only one trip_id-route_id combinaison for each stop_id but how can I list all the trip_is-route_id when there are more than one for a stop_id? (which is almost always the case).

Comment: could you update the question s.t. it better reflects the data? There, you only have one trip-route combinations.

Comment: I could try but I showed in the outcome part that every ```stop``` could have more than one ```trip``` related to it (but each ```trip``` only has one ```route``` related to it).